# Login with OAuth 2.0

Tags: authentication, keycloak, camunda, formsflow.ai

I managed to install the dockers and they are running without errors. I couldn't identify the problem with Camunda authentication that happens when we try to access the url: http://192.168.62.148:8000/camunda.

I need help to solve this problem.

[Image error login Camunda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fagkM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have a few ideas

- Check keycloak URL in your config
- Regenerate new client credentials key

Did you login first time?

Comment: Hello,
I followed your suggestions and the problem persists.

If there is someone who can support me and can contact me by skype: emersong2.

Thanks.